# Why does a docker container need more RAM at startup than during operation?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, out-of-memory, ram

I have a docker compose file with multiple docker containers. If I put these Docker containers in *depends_on* one after the other, all containers start without problems and I end up with 300MB of RAM memory left.

But when I try to start all containers at the same time I get an OOM error.
**Is the increased RAM consumption normal?**

If so, could someone tell me if it is coming from the Docker side (extra processes being started) or if it is possibly due to my container.

Comment: That seems unusual to me – just adding in `depends_on:` won't cause much difference in the startup sequence, some container startups might be delayed by several milliseconds – but without a [mcve] it's a little hard to tell.

Comment: @DavidMaze I link here once my other detailed question about it. I will do some more research and then answer it myself. I didn't know at the time of the question that depends_on: was the problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65611197/after-reboot-docker-compose-is-throwing-oom-killer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The increased ram is completely normal in your case. By using the depends_on flag you are spinning up each container one at a time and without it you are spinning up multiple containers concurrently.

Docker-compose is going to use extra RAM behind the scenes to spin up your containers. Because it worked using the depends_on flag each container had that extra RAM and therefore was able to launch. Without the depends_on flag and therefore the concurrent launch I’m assuming the amount of RAM surpassed the 300MB that you had available.

I would recommend configuring memory limits and reservations for each container - especially with a scenario like yours where your RAM is very limited.

Comment: Thank you! I even tried that, but unfortunately it didn't work. 
I'm not sure (and can't find an answer) if the limitation also works for the background processes, but apparently not.

Do you possibly know a documentation/link which additional processes are used when starting a container?

Comment: Checkout this link. You may need to use docker-compose in a cloud environment because of how much RAM docker needs. https://blimpup.io/blog/common-docker-compose-mistakes/